# How to get key value from JSON response using Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: json, api, jenkins, jira

I am successfully able to use a CURL command (Jenkins API) in a Jenkins pipeline to create a JIRA ticket and I get back a response {"id":"123456","key":"PROJECT-123","self":"url"}. The values in the response will change every time the build is ran.

My issue is the next step in the process which is to attach a file to that new JIRA ticket. How can I extract the key value (PROJECT-123) so that I can do another CURL command to add an attachment to that JIRA key?